# CompositeELResolver Null Pointer Exception

Tags: apache, jakarta-ee, el, geronimo, apache-tomee

I've got a problem with "javax.el.CompositeELResolver" which is used by TomEE's "javaee-api-6.0-5.jar".

Version information and svn-repository here:
http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.geronimo.specs/geronimo-el_2.2_spec/1.0.2

Source of class CompositeELResolver here:
http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/geronimo/specs/tags/geronimo-el_2.2_spec-1.0.2/src/main/java/javax/el/CompositeELResolver.java?view=log

In the "invoke" method I get a null pointer exception because the for-loop iterates through the whole resolvers-array which has got fields with value "null". I suppose this is not avoidable because of the "add" method that doubles the array size if required but does not initialize any values. Shouldn't there be a check if the resolver is "null" in the "invoke" method before using it?

For comparison I ran my application with another  javax.el implementation and it's working properly:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
  <artifactId>el-api</artifactId>
  <version>2.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Am I wrong with my supposition?

I found a similar-sounding issue here:
https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=50293

Is it possible that multi-threading causes my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved.

TomEE uses version 1.0.2 of http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.geronimo.specs/geronimo-el_2.2_spec

The bug is fixed in version 1.0.4

Answer (score 0):

Based on the fixed geronimo el spec 1.0.4 version it is easy to fix the javaee-api-6.0-5.jar package.

Just download the newest jar file from here http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.geronimo.specs/geronimo-el_2.2_spec/1.0.4

and change the javax.el package in javaee-api-6.0-5.jar with the files comes from geronimo el 2.2 spec 1.0.4 jar files

I did it using mc under linux browse the content and copy from one to another. And I tested and works perfect.

Of course you can do it with jar utils as well :-)

It was strange for me that this problem did not exist in 32 bit windows environment but only in 64 bit linux environment. Anyhow the fix solves the problem.

Hope that there will be a javaee-api-6.0-6.jar soon :-)